# i'm to expression engine . i hav a requirement like , i need to upload a file in images folder throug module

Tags: file-uploads

actually i need to make one small insertion form in module  . in that text fields are inserted but now i need to add a file in tat form . mod file code is like these 
 let me know wat to add the code for upload file in these.

function form()
    {
        $tagdata = ee()->TMPL->tagdata;

```
    $channel_id = (ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('channel_id') === FALSE) ? '0' : ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('channel_id');
    $entry_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id');
    $name = '';
    // Configure the upload class
        $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->EE->load->library('upload', $config);

        // Error checking
        if ( ! $this->EE->upload->do_upload('proposal_file'))
        {
            $data = array(
              'error' => $this->EE->upload->display_errors()
            );

        }
        // No problems so do our processing
        else
        {
            // Store the info about the uploaded file
            $upload_data = $this->EE->upload->data();
        }       
    $data['id']     = (ee()->TMPL->form_id == '') ? 'proposallist_form' : ee()->TMPL->form_id;
    $data['class']  = ee()->TMPL->form_class;
    $data['hidden_fields'] = array(
        'ACT'   => ee()->functions->fetch_action_id('Proposallist', 'insert_new_proposal'),
        'RET'   => ee()->functions->fetch_current_uri(),
        'channel_id'    => $channel_id,
        'entry_id'  => $entry_id,
    );
    $res  = ee()->functions->form_declaration($data);

    $res .= $tagdata;

    $res .= "</form>";

    return $res;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

/** ----------------------------------------
/**  Insert new email
/** ----------------------------------------*/
function insert_new_proposal()
{
    ee()->lang->loadfile('proposallist');
    if (ee()->config->item('proposallist_enabled') == 'n')
    {
        return ee()->output->show_user_error('general', lang('proposallist_disabled'));
    }
    if (ee()->blacklist->blacklisted == 'y' && ee()->blacklist->whitelisted == 'n')
    {
        return ee()->output->show_user_error('general', lang('not_authorized'));
    }

    if ( ! isset($_POST['RET']))
    {
        exit;
    }
    $errors = array();

    $proposal_file = ee()->input->post('proposal_file');
    $description = ee()->input->get_post('description');
    $member_id = $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id');
    $proposal_amount = ee()->input->post('proposal_amount');
    $proposal_date = ee()->input->post('delivery_date');
    $description = trim(strip_tags($description));
    $entry_id = ee()->input->post('entry_id');
    $proposal_agreement = ee()->input->post('agreement');
    $proposal_status = ee()->input->post('status');
    $pro_user_name = $this->EE->session->userdata('screen_name');
    $pro_email_id = $this->EE->session->userdata('email');
//exit();

    $proposal_id = FALSE;

    if ($description == '')
    {
        $errors[] = lang('ml_missing_email');
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0)
    {

            $query = ee()->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM exp_proposal_list WHERE member_id = '".ee()->db->escape_str($member_id)."' and entry_id = '".ee()->db->escape_str($entry_id)."'");

            if ($query->row('count')  > 0)
            {
                $errors[] = lang('Your have already submitted your proposal to this content need');
            }

    }

    $code = ee()->functions->random('alnum', 10);

    $return = '';

    ee()->db->query("INSERT INTO exp_proposal_list (proposal_id,entry_id,member_id,proposal_amount,proposal_date,description,pro_user_name,pro_email_id,proposal_status,proposal_file,proposal_accept_seller,proposal_accept_buyer,proposal_timestamp,proposal_agreement)
```

VALUES ('".ee()->db->escape_str($proposal_id)."', '".$entry_id."','".$member_id."','".$proposal_amount."','".$proposal_date."','".ee()->db->escape_str($description)."','".$pro_user_name."','".$pro_email_id."','".$proposal_status."','".$proposal_file."',' ',' ', '".$proposal_timestamp."', '".$proposal_agreement."')");

```
    ee()->functions->redirect($_POST['RET']);
}
```